# How to call wcf method which has key/value params via jquery?

Tags: ajax, wcf, jquery

Hi; i have a question for calling wcf service. how to fill data array Key/Value pair? How to efficiently send collaction via jquery?

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
            var val = [];
            var names = [];
            $('#cblist :checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
                val[i] = $(this).val();
                names[i] = $(this).attr('name');
            });

        });


<div id="cblist">"Dynamically filling"</div>
 <br />
     <input type="button" class="btn" value="AddParameter" id="btn" name="btnDelete" />
```

**i dislike this below  method(but below codes not working)Do you prefer this? if you prefer, how can i write correct coding?**

```
for (var i in names,val) data.push({ name: names[i], value: val[i] });
    $.ajax({
       url: "echo/json/",
       data: data,
       dataType: "json",
       traditional: true,
       success: function(msg){alert(msg)}
    });
```

But i can not: i dislike call wcf service each array items. i will write 2 kind of wvf service:

First one is :

```
Service1.svc/AddParameter:

public void AddParameters(int id, params string[] names, params string[] values)
{
    //dosomething
}
```

Second one is :

```
Service2.svc/AddParameter:

public void AddParameters(int id, NameValueCollection  NameswithValues)
{
    //dosomething

}
```

Summary; i want to prepare data array for json format: data{ id: 1, name1:value1, name2,value2..........n}, an then call Service1 and Service2. which one is efficient method?

My main question is : how to write efficient json ajax method which ic calling Service1.svc and Service2.svc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
var data;    
$('#cblist :checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {

                   data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
                });
```

Then just pass data in your ajax call.